# ANDROID: getting latitude&longitude in other class, but the value become 0.0

Tags: java, android, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have two classes.. First.java and Second.java,

In the First class.. latitude, longitude, and address show correctly in TextView.
But in Second class, latitude and longitude become 0.0 , address becomes null.

Can anyone help me why?

Here's the code for First.java

```
public class First extends Activity {
private Context context=null;
AppLocationService appLocationService;


String address;
double latitude;
double longitude;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_location);

    context=this;
    appLocationService = new AppLocationService(First.this);

    btngetLocation=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_getLocation);

    btngetLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // getting GPS status
            boolean isGPSEnabled = appLocationService
                    .getStatus(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            // getting network status
            boolean isNetworkEnabled = appLocationService
                    .getStatus(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if( isGPSEnabled==false && isNetworkEnabled==false){
                showSettingsAlert("Location Service");                  
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "Attempt to get location...Please Wait.. ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if( isNetworkEnabled ==true ){
                Location nwLocation = appLocationService
                            .getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (nwLocation == null){
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Network bermasalah.. Pastikan Anda terkoneksi Internet, dan coba get Location lagi",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                     latitude = nwLocation.getLatitude();
                     longitude = nwLocation.getLongitude();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Mobile Location (NW): \nLatitude: " + latitude
                                    + "\nLongitude: " + longitude,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Location gpsLocation = appLocationService
                            .getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (gpsLocation == null){
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "GPS bermasalah.. Silahkan di ruangan terbuka atau aktifkan network provider Anda, dan coba get Location lagi",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                    latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();
                    longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Mobile Location (GPS): \nLatitude: " + latitude
                                    + "\nLongitude: " + longitude,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                }
            }               

        }
    });

}


public class AppLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener{
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;


    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE = 10; //10 meter
    private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 1000 * 60 * 3; //3 menit

    public AppLocationService(Context context) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    public boolean getStatus(String provider){
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider); / 
    }

    public Location getLocation(String provider) {
                  MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                return location;
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}

public  String getAddress(Context ctx, double latitude, double longitude) {
   // StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String alamat=null;
    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String jalan = (address.getAddressLine(0));
            String locality=address.getLocality();
            String country=address.getCountryName();
            String country_code=address.getCountryCode();
            String zipcode=address.getPostalCode();

            alamat = jalan +", "+ locality +", "+ country+", " + country_code+", " + zipcode;

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

    return alamat; 
}



public double getLatitude(){
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    return longitude;
}


public String getAlamat(){
    return address;
}
```

Here's Second. java

```
public class Second extends Activity{

AddLocation data_dr_location;

 Double latitude;
 Double longitude;
 String address;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_description);

    data_dr_location = new AddLocation(); 

    address= data_dr_location.getAlamat();
    latitude = data_dr_location.getLatitude();
    longitude = data_dr_location.getLongitude(); }
```

Comment: you are initializing a new instance data_dr_location = new AddLocation();  and getting location, latitude and longitude so it will obviously be 0. You actually need to pass data from class1 to class2 using intent. I assume both classes are activity classes.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela : Thanks.. Yes, both classes are activity classes. But when I removed data_dr_location = new AddLocation(); , the second class crashed. Is there any other wrong?

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia I didn't find the mark. Sorry.. I am new here.

Comment: @vhiefa ... as i wrote you need to pass data from one activity to another. Also if you remove initialization code then obviously the current instance is null and not initialized, so will give NPE and will crash as i see you have not used any try catch. pl check this link http://hmkcode.com/android-passing-java-object-another-activity/ for knowing how to pass class object from one activity to another . Also as others mentioned you need to add setter method to set the value for variables.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela Thanks for the link. I have followed it and it worked like a charm. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first java, there is only getter method and no setter method!

```
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private String address;

public double getLatitude(){
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    return longitude;
}


public String getAlamat(){
    return address;
}

/*  THE BELOW SETTER METHODS ARE MISSING IN YOUR CODE.*/
public void setLatitude(double latitude){
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public void setLongitude(double longitude){
    this.longitude=longitude;
}


public setAlamat(String address){
    this.address=address;
}
```

At appropriate location (say whereever you get lat/long/address), add these lines.

```
 latitude = nwLocation.getLatitude();
     setLatitude (latitude);
 longitude = nwLocation.getLongitude();
     setLongitude (longitude);
```

Comment: @vhiefa: Please acknowledge answer by accepting it as answer. Click on the grey tick mark next to the answer to accept as answer.

Comment: @vhiefa: By the side of this answer, you will be finding a grey tick mark. You will have to check it and make it as green to accept as answer. You would get +2 points for accepting an answer

Answer (score 1):

your are only getting value.means you have written getter mehtod. you have not set value using setter method. please try that and check.

```
public void setLatitude(double latitude){
this.latitude = latitude;
 }

public void setLongitude(double longitude){
this.longitude=longitude;
} 


public setAlamat(String address){
 this.address=address;
}
```